# How to find all EABI versions a GCC supports and how to find an EABI version of the target system?

Tags: linux, gcc, android-ndk, build-process, arm

Two questions here:

1. When porting a shared library to many Linux-or-Android-on-ARM systems it is desirable to know the exact EABI versions a GCC cross-compiler does support and which EABI version is default. How to do it?
2. How to investigate which EABI has a target Linux-or-Android system? I usually take any system library from the target board and call `$ARM-GCC-PREFIX-readelf -h $LIBNAME | grep Flags` which returns me smth. like `Version4 EABI`. But is there any beautiful method so that I don't need to copy a system library from target to the host to run `readelf`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you've already found the one true way to identify what ABI a file uses. I don't know of a better way than `readelf`.

Similarly, `readelf` is probably the best way to determine the default ABI used by a compiler.

The compiler does not actually allow you to select any particular ABI version. It only allows you to choose between the various ABI variants. The compiler merely implements whatever is the current ABI at the time it was written. The EABI is supposed to be backwards compatible anyway.

Perhaps the real question is what architecture is supported? Or what float-abi? Those *are* important when building for a particular device.